# How to code in google sheet that retains the selected cell reference even after inserting a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need help in updating the value of the cell automatically based on the last value inserted on the sheet.

Basically, I just wanted the sheet to automatically update the balance (row 1, col I) every time I insert a row below the header (row 2).

The balance should work this way:
running balance (basis is always in row 3) MINUS the issued amount (column D) that has not been listed in columns E to J.

I have tried using this formula:
**running balance MINUS issued amount** but whenever i add another row, the basis of running balance will also move to row 4, which instead should remain in row 3 (so i don't have to keep changing the formula every time i add another row).

[image: my sheet looks like this]

Comment: Have you used the `OFFSET` function before?

Comment: no, i haven't tried OFFSET

Comment: You should try it. It does the job much better than `INDIRECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `INDIRECT` to freeze the reference and make it static. example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A"))
```

Comment: is indirect same as INDEX?

Comment: @swayingtrees no, its not